# Passing strings with numbers to Python - Why is my script failing?

Tags: function, python-2.7

I am doing [LPTHW exercise 48](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html) and I had rewritten my function several times. I deleted everything and wanted to start from scratch so I narrowed my problem to a one single one.

If I pass string containing number to the `scan` function, I want it to print string 'number' and the string that was passed. I'm having a problem where the string containing number is not recognized and instead returns None.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the short script:

```
def scan(user_input):

    direction = ['north', 'south',
                 'east', 'west', 'down',
                  'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']

    number = range(0,99999)

    try:
        if user_input in direction:
            print 'direction', direction[direction.index(user_input)]

        else:
            return None

    except ValueError:

        if int(user_input) in number:
            print 'number', user_input

        else:
            return None


scan(raw_input("> "))
```

If you pass for example 'north' to the function, it works fine however when you pass '123' you get None.

Comment: '123' is not in the direction list, so the else path will be followed in this case

Comment: OK if I put `else: pass` it still doesn't do anything... are the conditionals badly structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because an exception never occurs, so the `else` part under `try` returns `None`.

```
try:
    if user_input in direction:
        print 'direction', direction[direction.index(user_input)]
    elif int(user_input) in number:
        print 'number', user_input
    else:
        return None
except ValueError:
    return None
```

Comment: OK but what if you put `if int(user_input) in number` on the beginning? Then you get Value Error. How do I deal with this?

Comment: I've edited the post. You can return `None` if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wanted to do this basically:

```
def scan(user_input):

    direction = ['north', 'south',
                 'east', 'west', 'down',
                  'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']

    number = range(0,99999)


    try:
        if int(user_input) in number:
                print 'number', user_input
    except ValueError:
        if user_input in direction:
                print 'direction', direction[direction.index(user_input)]

        else:
            return None


scan(raw_input("> "))
```

I found out that the best way is to **check for integer first**, that's why right after `try:` I added `if int(user_input) in number:`.

Whenever that fails (because the string 'north' cannot be changed to `int`) it goes straight away to exception. If there's nothing found it returns `None`.

I want to thank you for hints though because it made me go through the code again and figure it out.